# Best practices to use subscriber inside a class

Tags: c++, pcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a wrapper class. A subscriber inside this wrapper class is supposed to subscribe to a point cloud rostopic and store the received point cloud in a class variable. A method inside this wrapper class named `getRecentData()` is supposed to return this class variable, i.e., point cloud data.

See the wrapper class below-

```
void PointCloudDataProvider::pointCloudCallback(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>& msg)
{
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc2;
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(*msg, pcl_pc2);
  pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2, *cloud);
}

void PointCloudDataProvider::init(std::string topic_name, int queue_size, PointCloudDataProvider point_cloud_data_provider)
{
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle;
  node_handle.subscribe(topic_name, queue_size, &PointCloudDataProvider::pointCloudCallback, &point_cloud_data_provider);
}

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr PointCloudDataProvider::getRecentData()
{
  return cloud;
}

// This doesn't work hence commented
/*
PointCloudDataProvider::PointCloudDataProvider(std::string topic_name, int queue_size)
{
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle;
  node_handle.subscribe(topic_name, queue_size, &PointCloudDataProvider::point_cloudCallback);
}
*/
// this is defined inside header file
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud;
```

Below is the test class-

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "point_cloud_data_provider_test");
  std::string topic = "/point_cloud/points";
  int size = 1;

  PointCloudDataProvider data_provider;
  data_provider.init(topic, size, data_provider);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
  while(1)
  {
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud = data_provider.getRecentData();
    // do something with point cloud here
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The above code doesn't work and shows following error-

```
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

Below are the reasons for creating the wrapper class-

1. The point cloud data is required by another method hence the processing cannot be done inside `pointCloudCallback` function
2. Use multiple instances of `PointCloudDataProvider` with different `rostopic`.
3. Access point cloud data from multiple instances of `PointCloudDataProvider` by using `getRecentData()` in almost same timestamp

Please note that point cloud data is not changing drastically since the scene is mostly static. Hence I didn't think about message synchronization. Also, message synchronization may be overkill for this task. Though I am not sure about it.

Following are my queries-

1. How do I make subscriber inside the class in this situation? Any workaround, please.
2. What are the best practices to use subscriber inside a class?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282707/best-practices-to-use-subscriber-inside-a-class/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2018-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Besides your compilation error the `PointCloudDataProvider::init(..)` method creates a `NodeHandle` instance with function-scope which will be destructed as soon as `init(..)` finishes. That is probably not what you want.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-02-14**:
Yes. You are right. Based on the reasons/requirements which I mentioned in the post, can you please suggest me the proper solution for this? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you must to create one node handle in your class such as:

```
class High_control
{
private:
       ros::NodeHandle n;
....
}
```

and in your init you should do something like this

```
rcInSubscriber     = n.subscribe<mavros_msgs::RCIn>("mavros/rc/in", 10, &High_control::RcIn,this);
```

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-02-17**:
Yeah! thanks a lot.